# Number of possible rectangles inscribed inside an equilateral triangle

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

**Problem**: The shape of a network is a big equilateral triangle as shown in the following picture and it consists of many small equilateral triangles of different sizes. Each point represents a computer and you have to choose a rectangle such that each of its corners is a computer and the horizontal edges are parallel with the lower edge of the network(big triangle) The size of the network is the number of small triangles on each edge of the big triangle. You need to count the number of rectangles that can be selected from the network.

[image]

**Requirement**: So the ask is generalization, can we come up with a formula to translate the size of a triangle (here `n`) to the number of rectangles possible.

Question taken from [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/implementation/basics-of-implementation/practice-problems/algorithm/mosalas-mostatilioo-f012275c/).

Comment: How far have you gotten with it?

Comment: Frankly, very little. Was not able to generalize the problem and the editorial was also of little help, hence the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the triangle has side $n$ then there are $n$ horizontal lines of dots, with $k$ dots in line number $k$.  If the top of the rectangle is in line $k$ then there are ${k\choose2}={k(k-1)\over2}$ ways to choose which two dots are at the corners.  Then then bottom of the rectangle must be an even number of rows below the top, so that the dots will line up.  Finally, we have $$\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}{k\choose2}\left\lfloor{n-k\over2}\right\rfloor$$ rectangles in all.

I haven't tried to simplify this further. If you want to try, I think it would be best to consider the cases $n$ even and $n$ odd separately.